# Using return with method inline

Tags: c#, inline

I want to inline a method with a `switch` block.

If I use the `return` in `switch` statements, will it break the `ParentMethod` execution?

```
void ParentMethod()
{
    InliningMethod(myEnum.SomeValue);

    //do some after inline for test case
    Console.WriteLine("Will this have been writed?"); 
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
void InliningMethod(MyEnum value)
{
    switch(myEnum)
    {
        case MyEnum.SomeValue:
            return; //will it have been moved in ParentMethod?
        default: break;       
    }
    //do some
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inlining does not mean the code just gets copied over. The compiler will get it right, the `return` only exits the method it's in, whether the compiler later inlines it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Inline method is just a style to write method in less code, it doesn't change execution principle. So, "return statement" inside inline method will not break parent method.